# math induction proving what if step one is falsy

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

What if the step one is falsy when checking the initial condition

What next can we do. Next step I think no so what it is proper to do

example prove that $3^{n+2}+6^{n+2}$ for any natural number $n\ge0$ is divisible by 15

$15a=3^{n+2}+6^{n+2}$   where $a\in \mathbb Z $

$n_0=0$

$15|3^{0+2}+6^{0+2}$

and I get $ 15|45 $

My question don't have sense because I get to know to not confuse $15|45$ with $45|15$ I thought $15|45$ is the same as $15 \div 45$ that's why this was unclear and first step is not falsy but true because $45 \div 15$

Comment: Please edit your question to be a little more clear. I barely got what you are asking.

Comment: You could check the case $n=2$, and if that is true and the induction step also works then you have proved the result for all $n \ge 2$

Comment: Maybe give an example to clarify the question. In general, if the base case is false, then the conclusion you try to prove is false since you just found a counterexample to it.

Comment: Search for the first step (with logic or just trying out increasingly larger first steps). Depending on what you want to prove, if the first step doesn't work, you showed that what you want to show isn't working.

Comment: "*prove that $3^{n+2}+6^{n+2}$ is divisible by 15*" The statement fails for $n=1$, since $3^3+6^3=243$ is not a multiple of $15$. Therefore the statement is false, and so it cannot be proved.

Comment: It is *true* for $\,n=0\,$ since $\,15\mid 45.\,$ It is true $\iff 4\mid n\,$ since that's when it is divisible by $\,5.\,$ (It is always divisible by $\,3).$ $\ $ Are you trying to prove that it is *not* divisible by $15?\ $

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To respond to your example: Recall that "$a$ divides $b$" means that $na = b$ for some whole number $n$. $3 \cdot 15 = 45$, so $15$ does divide $45$; the statement is therefore *true* when $n = 0$.

Regarding what you seem to be asking, however: If the base case is false, the statement you are trying to prove is false. A simple example is this: Suppose I asked you to prove that all swans are white. You go out to find some swans, and the first swan you find is black. You wouldn't be confused about what to do next - you'd just know that I was wrong.

On the other hand, sometimes the thing you're trying to prove is *almost* true - that is, it's true once $n$ gets big enough. For example, $2^n > 3$. For $n = 0$, this is false - $2^0 = 1 < 3$. But the induction step works: if $2^n > 3$, then $2^{n + 1} = 2 \cdot 2^n > 2 \cdot 3 > 3$. So once it *starts* being true, it'll always be true. That just means we have to use a different base case; in this case, we start with $n = 2$, because that's the first $n$ for which $2^n > 3$. The end result is that what we prove is *not* "For all $n$, $2^n > 3$", because that's false; instead, we show that "For all $n \geq 2$, $2^n > 3$".